# Do new computers still come with RS-232 ports?

Tags: rs232

Is the RS-232 port still being used on new computer or is it going to be deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232

The description under "role in modern personal computers" explains the current state of the interface decently.

"Many fields (for example, laboratory automation, surveying) provide a continued demand for RS-232 I/O due to sustained use of very expensive but aging equipment. It is often far cheaper to continue to use RS-232 than it is to replace the equipment. Additionally, modern industrial automation equipment, such as PLCs, VFDs, servo drives, and CNC equipment are programmable via RS-232. Some manufacturers have responded to this demand: Toshiba re-introduced the DE-9M connector on the Tecra laptop."

The interface has been around for a long time and for the most part been replaced with USB. It has been removed by default from most new systems.  Expansion cards and usb adapters will be available for some time.  There are a few new laptop systems that come with serial ports in responce to the request for native serial db9 ports for legacy equipment support. These are usually found in "business" lines of machines.

Answer (score 4):

Most new PCs from manufacturers like Dell no longer include serial ports.

You can get a usb adapter or an expansion card for it though.

Comment: One thing about the USB->Serial adapters is that they don't always play well with older hardware...

Comment: True Timo.  Also they are a PITA to configure sometimes.

Comment: Sometimes you need to try several different brands to find the one that meshes with your hardware.